# Hungarian cartoon from 60s

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

Can anybody identify a Hungarian cartoon from the 60s where a brother and sister stole their uncle's spaceship in order to fly to Mars to discover Martians. On their way they got stained by rainbow and washed with rain; they had breakfast on the moon; they span on Jupiter's rings; by mistake they lowered their spaceship to the wrong planet and crashed. They were saved by their uncle and a space taxi driver.

Comment: They "span" on Jupiter's rings? What does "span" mean?

Comment: You might get some mileage out of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Hungarian_animation - it has a long list by year.

Comment: spun on Jupiter's rings

Comment: Otis, thank you so much! It's from a cartoon series from early 60s by Gyula Macskássy. I only found the very first episode Peter and the robot (Peti és a gépember) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1e-LH1K-8M

Comment: If anyone here speaks hungarian, the name of the episode that I am looking for could be either Peti and martians OR Peti and trip to space or something like this...

Answer (score 7):

I think original animation is **Peti és a marslakók / Peti and martians**, because it was also published as a book: [**Peti és a marslakók**](https://www.antikvarium.hu/konyv/varnai-gyorgy-peti-es-a-marslakok-536441):

[image]

[image]

[**Russian version**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrsAVbb96q8) of that book is called **Pete and trip to space (Петя и путешествие в космос)**, which looks a bit like hungarian **Peti vidám űrutazása / Peti's merry space trip**.

Nevertheless it contains the same pictures as
original hungarian version, so I assume it is actually translation of **Peti and martians**:

[image]

[image]

Adding here pictures to match the plot from russian version:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And even martians:

[image]

I also searched for video: no luck for now.